# having difficulty to understand this while loop?

Tags: tcl, glyph

I have difficulty understanding this while loop:

[image]

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I have attached the code in the Image. e

Comment: set mode [pw::Application begin ExtrusionSolver $block]

  set result Completed
  while {1 == [string equal $result Completed]} {
    $mode run
    set result [lindex [$mode getRunResult] 0]
    switch $result {
      Error -
      SolverFailure {
        puts "Extrusion solver encountered an error"
      }
      Completed -
      StopCriteria {
      }
    }
  }

  $mode end
}

Comment: @KaranSoni it would be helpful if you could explain what about this loop you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

### The Condition

The condition:

```
while {1 == [string equal $result Completed]} {
```

could be written more shortly as:

```
while {$result eq "Completed"} {
```

That is, it means "do the body while `$result` is equal to the literal string `Completed`.

### The Body

The body of the loop calls `$mode run` (what exactly that does isn't described here). Then it gets the result by calling `$mode getRunResult` and extracts the first word of the list, and assigns it to the variable `result`. The final step of the loop is to use `switch` to print a message whenever `$result` is either `Error` or `SolverFailure` (it also has clauses for `Completed` and `StopCritera`, but that's empty so nothing happens).

### The Overall Effect

The loop calls `$mode run` until the first word of the result of `$mode getRunResult` after that run is not `Completed`.

`$mode` is a handle returned by `pw::Application begin ExtrusionSolver $block`, and `$mode end` is called after the loop terminates, presumably to clean things up.

Comment: The setting of `result` to `Completed` before the loop just means that we're going to definitely run the loop body at least once.